# How to append a row to html table using DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to add a row to a HTML table in pure JS as follows,

```
    var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('table1_out').getElementsByTagName("TBODY");
    var row = document.createElement("TR");

    var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml1 = "<?php echo $addNewCurrencyPOST["id"] ?>";
    td1.innerHTML = strHtml1;

    var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml2 = "<div class='led on'></div>";
    td2.innerHTML = strHtml2;

    var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml3 = "<?php echo $addNewCurrencyPOST["symbol"] ?>";
    td3.innerHTML = strHtml3;

    var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml4 = "<?php echo $addNewCurrencyPOST["symbolhtml"] ?>";
    td4.innerHTML = strHtml4;

    var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml5 = "<?php echo $addNewCurrencyPOST["usdrate"] ?>";
    td5.innerHTML = strHtml5;

    var td6 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml6 = "<?php echo $addNewCurrencyPOST["eurrate"] ?>";
    td6.innerHTML = strHtml6;

    var td7 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml7 = '';
    td7.innerHTML = strHtml7;

    // append data to row
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    row.appendChild(td5);
    row.appendChild(td6);
    row.appendChild(td7);

    // append row to table
    tbody.appendChild(row);
```

And this is the structure of the table,

```
<div class="table1_out">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Symbol</th>
                    <th>Symbol html</th>
                    <th>Exchange rate EUR</th>
                    <th>Exchange rate USD</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>EUR</td>
    <td><div class="led on"></div></td>
    <td>€</td>
    <td>&amp;euro;</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.319810</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="document.location.href='/backoffice_dev.php/currency/edit/EUR';"></td>
</tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But it is throwing the error:

> TypeError: tbody.appendChild is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your `tbody` is actually an array-like object, as in `[<tbody>]`:

```
var tbody = (...).getElementsByTagName("TBODY");
```

You're using "get **Elements**", which returns a node list. Take the first of those:

```
var tbody = (...).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
```

Comment: actually, not an array, but a _live node list_, which happens to support the array accessor semantics

Answer (score 2):

The `var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('table1_out').getElementsByTagName("TBODY");`
reference a node list.

You need to do like this:

```
var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('table1_out').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
```